# psql command is failing silently

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, psql

When I run this from the terminal session:

```
   => psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str"
```

and then execute:

```
   => ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
      ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 320);
```

then it fails with:

> constraint "email_too_long_ln_check" for relation "cp_user_emails"
>   already exists

but if I run this:

```
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" -c "$(<<EOF

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_non_zero_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) > 4);

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 321);

EOF
)"
```

then the query "succeeds" and there is no error message! but when I look at the db it's the same as before, so it's clearly either not reaching the db, or failing silently..

so why it isn't the query failing / exiting with 1 with an error message when I run it as a script instead of directly in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" -f <(cat <<EOF

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_non_zero_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) > 4);

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 321);

EOF
)
```

but this doesn't:

```
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" -c "$(<<EOF

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_non_zero_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) > 4);

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 321);

EOF
)"
```

but I realized I need to read it with cat, so this works:

```
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" -c "$(cat <<EOF

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_non_zero_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) > 4);

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 321);

EOF
)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement is the same as

```sh
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" -c "$()"
```

because that command ignores its standard input

If you want to use a “here document” with `psql`, do this:

```sh
psql "$pg_cp_prod_conn_str" <<EOF
ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_non_zero_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) > 4);

ALTER TABLE cp_user_emails
  ADD CONSTRAINT email_too_long_ln_check CHECK (char_length(TRIM(email)) < 321);

EOF
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got `psql: option requires an argument -- 'c'`

Comment: so if I use `-c` then it expects a string after it

Comment: I figured it out, added an answer

Comment: @AlexChannelmeter You don't need the `-c` option, as shown in my answer.